# MySQL joins confuse me and I always get syntax errors

Tags: mysql, join

I need to fetch some data from a `MySQL` db. I have the function working using two separate, simple queries, but i'm sure this is probably achievable with one query using a `JOIN`. `SQL` isn't my strong point and I keep getting syntax errors when I try. Sure, I could leave it as it is, why not, it works. But i would prefer to see a real world example of how they can be joined so i can try and apply it on other queries in the future.

Query one is:

```
select manufacturers_id from products where products_name = product a
```

The result is then put into a variable and used in the following

```
select manufacturers_name from manufacturers where manufacturers id = $man_id
```

So, basically, the `products` table holds the `manufacturers_id`, which we need to collect for a given product to find out what the manufacturers name is from the `manufacturers` table. 
`manufacturers_id` is the common field.

Comment: I always liked [visual example of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.manufacturers_name 
FROM products a
LEFT JOIN manufacturers b ON a.manufacturers_id = b.manufacturers_id
WHERE a.products_name = 'PRODUCT NAME'
```

Below is a diagram of `SQL Joins`

[image: SQL JOINS]

[Image Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Please provide attribution for the image source, unless you are its creator.

Comment: A +1 for the excellent diagram you provided which clearly and simply shows the join process. Thank you ever so much, a massive help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for

```
SELECT manufacturers.manufacturers_name
FROM products
JOIN manufacturers on manufacturers_id=products.manufacturers_id
WHERE manufacturers_name='product a'
```

With a join, you just need to follow this syntax, and remember that you have to set the matching columns equal to each other so you don't end up with invalid rows.

I'd show you how the equivalent of this using table joins, but I really don't want to encourage the use of that syntax, even by accident.

Comment: Your solution produces a syntax error too. #1052 - Column 'manufacturers_id' in on clause is ambiguous

Comment: hard to do without your table structures. I assumed the name didn't exist on the first table since you were performing a join to get it. The sql is corrected, but it still might fail if table / column names are off. We cannot guess what those are, you may have corrections to make.

Comment: Apologies, i should have included table structures in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select m.manufacturers_name from products p, manufacturers m
 where p.products_name = 'productA' and p.manufacturers_id = m.id
```